# ZoomChange or centerChange events for angular maps?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, maps, zooming

Hello I am currently working for a project in which we use **Angular Maps**, using **Angular 6** for the front and **Python** for the back.

What I need is to bring from the API the corded points of a certain range of kilometers. I already have the written code, I just need to be able to **detect the change of zoom and center of coordinates in real time**?

I could detect these changes from the file `map.js` (own file of the Angular Maps library), but I can not change values of my main **component** from this file.

Is there any way to be able to detect zoom and center changes?

What I'm looking for is a function very similar to:

```
(mapClick) = "MyFunction1($event)"
```

but in this way:

```
(zoomChange)="MyFunction2()"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem, likewise leave the solution in case someone needs it.

**Step 1:** In your file `.html` add

```
<agm-map [zoom]="mapa_cfg.zoom" [latitude]="mapa_cfg.latitud" [longitude]="mapa_cfg.longitud"(zoomChange)="zoomChange($event)" (centerChange)="centerChange($event)">
```

**Step 2:** In your file `.ts` add

```
zoomChange(event){
    console.log(event);
}

centerChange(event){
    console.log(event);
}
```